# how to copy file or directory to remote machine using sftp

Tags: cloud, remote-access, sftp, virtualhost

I used this command `sftp  cbuser@10.250.41.20` to start session with a remote virtual machine on the cloud and tried to copy files from my local machine to that machine and I used this command : `put l1/l2/file.tar.gz  /rl1`
Unfortunately, I got the following error :

```
remote open("/rl1"): Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

This command

```
put l1/l2/file.tar.gz  /rl1
```

copies file to the remote root directory (`/`), which is probably not what you want (and as a normal user, you certainly don't have access for this). You probably want to copy the file to your home directory (`~`) like this:

```
put l1/l2/file.tar.gz  ~/rl1
```

or current directory

```
put l1/l2/file.tar.gz  ./rl1
```

or

```
put l1/l2/file.tar.gz  rl1
```

This should work for you.